# How to add custom action into the Pages tab of publishing page?

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, custom-actions

I want to add a custom action in the Pages of tab which comes when I edit the page. The publishing page is stored in the Pages Library.

To made thing for single list(i.e. Pages Library) I have created a custom action for the content type.

**My declarative part is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="ContentTypeRibbonCustomization" 
                RegistrationId="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39009A2F8A780CB442EC9899AD3D4A097C86"
                RegistrationType="ContentType" 
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm" Sequence="95" Title="Ribbon Customization for a Content Type">
    <CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <!-- Define the (UI) button to be used for this custom action -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="{B511A716-54FF-4EAE-9CBE-EA02B51B626E}"
          Command="{4E2F5DC0-FE2C-4466-BB2D-3ED0D1917763}"
          Image32by32="~site/_layouts/Images/BingSearch/bing32.png"
          Image16by16="~site/_layouts/Images/BingSearch/bing16.png"
          Sequence="0"
          LabelText="Bing It!"
          Description="Search Title on Bing"
          TemplateAlias="o1"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <!-- Define the action expected on the button click -->
        <CommandUIHandler Command="{4E2F5DC0-FE2C-4466-BB2D-3ED0D1917763}" CommandAction="javascript:alert('hello');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I am getting the output in the View form like:

[image]

I want to insert the same here..

[image: Page tab]

I searched over internet for adding the custom action in Page tab but couldn't find it.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you try to set location attribute to Ribbon.List.Manage.Controls._children and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for responding sir, I made the following changes:
`<CustomAction Location="CommandUI.Ribbon".../>` & `<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.Manage.Controls._children">` but not working